# What kind of whiskey is served cold?

Tags: whiskey

I really like my alcoholic beverages cold. But I do know most whiskeys should be served in room temperature.

Although adding ice is an option, I do not prefer this method because when ice melts, the whiskey is mixed with water.
Using [whiskey stones](http://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/zoom/ba37_whiskey_stones2.jpg) is good for drinking at home, but I cannot carry my stones around (for instance in a bar).

So, what type of whiskey is served chilly so I can order that one when I go to a bar?

Comment: OK, not up on certain things, What are whiskey stones?

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 they are stones in cubic shape, which you put in the freezer, then use as ice cubes.

Comment: Ah, that was what I thought!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: It is not common. I am surprised Jamie found one. +1 Jägermeister is common to be served cold but it is not a whiskey. If they serve beer in frozen mugs you could ask for a shot in a frozen beer mug.

Comment: @dougal5.0.0 From personal experience - I wouldn’t recommend them. Similar to ice cubes, the stones often absorb foreign odors and tastes which ruin the beverage. Though granted I may have not been careful enough in how they were stored in the freezer (they come with a velvet-type bag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One whiskey that I know of is the [Snow Grouse](https://www.drinkfinder.co.uk/the-snow-grouse-blended-grain-whisky-40-70cl.html) it is a blended grain whiskey that as by the name is supposed to be drank cold.
 Some would even say that this whiskey is better straight from the freezer 
[image: Snow grouse bottle]

Comment: Although this may be meant to be served cold, I think the question is asking if there is a whiskey that he can order at a bar or restaurant that will be reliably served cold with adding ice. This would probably mean the bottle is stored refrigerated. I don't know of one.

Comment: @EricShain Actually, if this whiskey is to be served cold, then the bar should keep it cold (as they do with the white wine). Otherwise, I can ask them to serve it properly (or maybe I never get to drink cold whiskey).

Comment: Tell me if you find this particular whiskey at a bar served chilled.

Comment: 4 days, 13 bars and none of them serves this whiskey cold. But I will keep trying!

Answer (score 3):

I know of three at the moment.

The Snow Grouse was already mentioned and is supposed to be served straight from the freezer.

Dalwhinnie Winter's Gold is another one.

And very recently, Johnny Walker launched the White Walker (base on the Game of Thrones show).

A couple of remarks.
The Dalwhinnie expression is the only single malt among the named three. The others are blends of malt and other grains.
Any "other" whisky, I personally, would never drink chilled. Neither chilled with ice nor with stones. To explain why, just a little background. Some whisky's are "unchillfiltered" or "non chill filtered". If so, it says so on the bottle. These whisky's still contain lots of essential oils. Chilling them will cause these oils to coagulate and form a hazy draft in your dram. Not what I want.
With this in mind, using ice is bad because it will water down your drink on top of chilling it. Using stones is almost equally bad, because though your drink will not be diluted, it will still turn for the ugly.

So I would keep drinking whisky at room temp, and if you don't appreciate it now, you'll learn... If you still want a cold one, take one of the three mentioned, as they were purposely invented to this end.

Nick, board member of Angel's Share whisky club, Izegem, Belgium

Comment: Have an upvote for **most** of this answer. But be aware that saying that a particular way of drinking whisky is bad is, well, wrong. It is just an opinion. Some people like ice with some whiskies, some like water, and some like stones. They are all correct, and it doesn't help by treating them as if they are wrong. Any drink can be taken the way the individual prefers it.

Answer (score 2):

Flavored Whiskey is often kept in the freezer/ fridge:

**Fireball** (cinnamon whiskey), although weaker than most whiskey and far sweeter is consistently kept cold.

**American Honey** (Honey flavored Whiskey) is smooth and sweet but has more of a whiskey kick that Fireball.

There are several other kinds of flavored whiskey and many are kept refrigerated, but the above two are the most common.

For non-flavored the only whiskey I've seen kept on ice, although not consistently, is Yukon Jack.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve noticed that Jack Daniels -stocked at every bar- is typically served on ice (“chilly”), especially when mixed with coke.